# CEfsharp - OnDevToolsMessage

Tags: cefsharp, cefsharp.offscreen

The Description for the OnDevToolsMessage function says: https://cefsharp.github.io/api/94.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_Callback_IDevToolsMessageObserver_OnDevToolsMessage.htm

> Method that will be called on receipt of a DevTools protocol message.
> Method result dictionaries include an "id" (int) value that identifies
> the orginating method call sent from **IBrowserHost.SendDevToolsMessage**,
> and optionally either a "result" (dictionary) or "error" (dictionary)
> value. The "error" dictionary will contain "code" (int) and "message"
> (string) values. Event dictionaries include a "method" (string) value
> and optionally a "params" (dictionary) value. See the DevTools
> protocol documentation at
> https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/ for details of
> supported method calls and the expected "result" or "params"
> dictionary contents. JSON dictionaries can be parsed using the
> CefParseJSON function if desired, however be aware of performance
> considerations when parsing large messages (some of which may exceed
> 1MB in size).

But in the Browserhost method - there are two functions:
-ExecuteDevToolsMethod
-SendDevToolsMessage

Then it is not clear to me - if, according to the description, calling the OnDevToolsMessage function calls the OnDevToolsMessage function, then what does the ExecuteDevToolsMethod function do?? What function does it call ?

Comment: As the description says, Method that will be called on receipt of a DevTools protocol message. It's basically an event handler, it's called by Chromium. The other methods are for executing methods.

Comment: @ amaitland, But the OnDevToolsMessage method itself is not called , is it ?
It is called only after calling the SendDevToolsMessage function - which is what is written in the description. But then why the necessary ExecuteDevToolsMethod function ?

Comment: Think of SendDevToolsMessage and ExecuteDevToolsMethod as exactly the same functionality, just different parameters.

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/99.2.x/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_ExecuteDevToolsMethod_1.htm and http://cefsharp.github.io/api/99.2.x/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_SendDevToolsMessage.htm Both are documented